# SQL Like with a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, wildcard

How can i make this work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   item 
WHERE  item_name LIKE '%' 
                      || (SELECT equipment_type 
                          FROM   equipment_type 
                          GROUP  BY equipment_type) 
                      || '%'
```

The inner sub query returns a list of strings like 'The' 'test' 'another' and i want to select all items from the item table where the item_name is similar to the sub queries return values.  I need to have the wild cards.

Is there an alternative where i can use wildcards but use the IN sql command instead?

Comment: Don't you have ID to do this??

Comment: @TechBytes What do you mean?

Comment: @TechBytes i specifically stated that i have a list of strings i want to compare item_name to.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT I.* 
FROM item I
INNER JOIN (SELECT equipment_type 
            FROM equipment_type 
            GROUP BY equipment_type) E
    ON I.item_name LIKE '%' || E.equipment_type || '%'
```

Comment: ahhh nice nice, i will try this and let you know ASAP. ty

Comment: For those using SQL Server... The double pipes appears to be the ANSI-SQL standard but won't work in T-SQL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372550/what-does-sql-select-symbol-mean

Comment: Note that this solution produces duplicates.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to worry about duplicates and don't care which one matches, then switch to using `exists`:

```
select i.*
from item i
where exists (select 1
              from equipment_type
              where i.item_name like '%'||equipment_type||'%'
             )
```

Answer (score 4):

For MSSql Server above does not fly

Use

```
select *
from item I
where exists (select 1
          from equipment_type
          where i.item_name like (SELECT CONCAT('%',equipment_type,'%')) 
         )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CONCAT` and insert the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE  item_name LIKE  
CONCAT('%', (
    SELECT equipment_type
    FROM equipment_type
    GROUP BY equipment_type), '%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   item 
WHERE  item_name LIKE ANY  
                      (SELECT '%'|| equipment_type || '%' 
                          FROM   equipment_type 
                          GROUP  BY equipment_type)
```

Comment: Please explain the effect of what you propose and why it helps to solve the problem. Try for [answer].

Comment: In addition to @Yunnosch’s question, this question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.**